# Register a generic interface with a non generic implementation in ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IValidationResult<T> where T : struct {
        T Status { set; get; }
        User User { set; get; }
}
```

And a class that implements the generic interface:

```
public class ValidationResult : IValidationResult<ValidationResult.ValidationStatus> {
    public enum ValidationStatus { UserNotFound, InvalidPassword, Valid, UserBlankOrSpace }
    public ValidationStatus Status { set; get; }
    public User User { set; get; }

    public ValidationResult (User user, ValidationStatus status) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("The User is Null");
        }
        Status = status;
        User = user;
    }
}
```

I wanna register my interface so I can use DI(Dependency Injection), if both my class and the interface were generic I'd register them as:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(EFGenericRepository<>));
```

But it's possible to register a generic interface with a non generic implementation in ASP.NET Core using the built in Dependency Injection? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about

```
services.AddScoped<IValidationResult<ValidationResult.ValidationStatus>,
                   ValidationResult>();
```